# массовый Delete запрос в Postman

Tags: postman, delete

Есть несколько пользователей с одинаковым именем ("name"). (Не важно откуда они и почему)
Как можно с помощью Delete () запроса удалить этих пользователей одним запросом?
Спасибо.

Comment: В принципе конечно хорошо что вопрос не перегружен лишними деталями, но одна деталь все таки важна, поддерживает ли сервер такое удаление, потому что если он не поддерживает то Postman ничем не поможет, иными словами если конверты не влазят в ваш почтовый ящик каким бы ни был почтальон он максимум положит их под коврик или воткнет между дверью и калиткой) Если Вам нужен цикл в Postman то боюсь там его нет.

Comment: Проще всего для Вашей задачи воспользоваться Postman для генерации запроса на любом известном вам языке программирования и далее организовать там цикл в котором и скормить все нужные айдишники для удаления

Comment: Я еще в начале пути и возможно мои вопросы опережают мои знания, но все же. Допустим я создал генерацию запроса на любом известном мне языке программирования (без сарказма), дальше должна быть какая то интеграция с Postman это нужно настраивать VC Code (к примеру) с Postman? Спасибо.

Comment: Нет дальше запускаете этот код или компилируете и запускаете любым удобным Вам способом, Postman для выполнения не нужен совсем — он лишь предоставляет удобный способ получить код чтобы не набирать его самостоятельно.